# The [cv] tag - computer-vision or curiculum vitae

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request, synonym-request

There are only 69 questions with the [cv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv) tag, but it somehow got a tag wiki.
Almost all of the questions are about [computer-vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision), but I found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470402/programming-competitions-and-job-seeking) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433495/suggest-terms-to-describe-language-proficiency-level-in-your-cv) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784789/simple-remote-git-log-for-my-resume) about curicula vitae, and [one about const-volatility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682049/functions-with-const-arguments-and-overloading).

I would say add it as a synonym to [computer-vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision) (2677 questions), but because of the potential misunderstandings it might be safer to remove it entirely?

The problem with this tag has been discussed before in 2011:
[Is CV tag for "curriculum vitae" or "computer vision"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86366/is-cv-tag-for-curriculum-vitae-or-computer-vision)

I think that is how it got a tag wiki, but the current resolution to let it stand parallel to computer-vision seems unsatisfactory.

Comment: Questions tagged "curriculum vitae" would almost certainly be off-topic, so `computer-vision` it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[cv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv) is now syononymized to [computer-vision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision).

Comment: But there are still some questions related to career advices, like this -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470402/programming-competitions-and-job-seeking